# normalized cross correlation for characters

Tags: templates, character, matching

this the template matching correlation part

```
function letter=read_letter(img_r,num_letras)

% Computes the correlation between template and input image
% and its output is a string containing the letter.
% Size of 'imagn' must be 42 x 24 pixels
% Example:
% imagn=imread('D.bmp');
% letter=read_letter(imagn)
global templates
comp=[ ];
%while 1
for n=1:length(templates)
sem=corr2(templates{1,n},img_r); 
comp=[comp sem];  
end
vd=find(comp==max(comp));
if vd==1
letter='A';
elseif vd==2
letter='B';
........
else
letter='z';
end
```

template matching can various types.Is my template matching based on cross correlation?
I want to know how can I use Normalized cross correlation for recognizing characters

plz help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`corr2` already calculates the normalised correlation.
Compare the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalized_cross-correlation) of normalised cross-correlation and the matlab [implementation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/corr2.html#moreabout).